# Get list values outside the function separately

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, list

I try to somehow take these values ​​from the list outside the function separately

```
var dados = [ [ '*.cbn.com.bo', 21 ] ]

var convertida = dados.map(function(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).map(function(chave) {
        console.log(obj[chave]);
    });
});

console.log(convertida);
```

log function:

```
*.cbn.com.bo
21
```

log console.log

```
[ [ undefined, undefined ] ]
```

Comment: You do not have an object so why are you using `Object.keys`???

Comment: What is your expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```js
var dados = [ [ '*.cbn.com.bo', 21 ] ];
    
const [value1, value2] = dados.flat(1);

console.log(value1);
console.log(value2);
```